# Tried removing NOT NULL constraint using ALTER TABLE command in SAPHANA Table, but not reflected

Tags: sql, hana

I used the following two commands in SAPHANA sql console to remove NOT NULL constraint from those 2 columns SOFTWARE_CATEGORY_L0 and SOFTWARE_CATEGORY_L1:

```
ALTER TABLE pc_vpuc_qpps_stage ALTER (SOFTWARE_CATEGORY_L0 VARCHAR(15) NULL);
ALTER TABLE pc_vpuc_qpps_stage ALTER (SOFTWARE_CATEGORY_L1 VARCHAR(15) NULL);
```

Before running these commands, I checked Table definition(by clicking generate CREATE statement), and it showed SOFTWARE_CATEGORY_L0 VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL and SOFTWARE_CATEGORY_L1 VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL. After running the ALTER TABLE commands I checked Table definition again(by clicking generate CREATE statement) and now there is no NOT NULL constraint in the Table definition. So I thought the NOT NULL constraint is removed. However, when I just clicked the table to see the column properties(check the attachment), the column information is still showing that SOFTWARE_CATEGORY_L0 and SOFTWARE_CATEGORY_L1 are having NOT NULL constraint and also after inserting NULL data to these columns I am getting error message:

> (hdbcli.dbapi.DataError) (287, 'cannot insert NULL or update to NULL:
> Not nullable "SOFTWARE_CATEGORY_L0" column').

This error I should not get now, as I used ALTER TABLE command to remove NOT NULL constraint.
So, Please help me to understand and hence resolve the issue so that NOT NULL constraint is removed from those two columns in SAPHANA Table.
[column information snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOkkM.png)

Comment: I recommend checking that the `ALTER TABLE` commands were executed to the same schema/DB as the `INSERT` commands. The described situation appears to have a disconnect between the change of table definition and the data insert. If this is occurring with a HDI container schema, checking which instance of the container is used for each might help clarifiying this.